# How to count number of rows from a table using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get the count of number of rows from Vulnerability table based on the vulnerability and threat entered. But always i get a value None in place of vulnerability count.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "sharmi@08", "MySQL56");

// Check connection
if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$Vulnerability = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Vulnerability']);
$Threat = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Threat']);
/*$P_Vulnerability = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['P_Vulnerability']);*/
/*$P_Threat = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['P_Threat']);*/

$Threat_count = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Threat_count']);
$table = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Vul']);  
// attempt insert query execution

$sql = "INSERT INTO vuln_threat(Vulnerability, Threat) VALUES ('$Vulnerability', '$Threat') ";
$Vulnerability_count = mysqli("Select count(*) from vuln_threat");

$sql = "UPDATE vuln_threat SET Vulnerability_Count='$Vulnerability_count',Threat_Count='1' WHERE Vulnerability='".$Vulnerability."' AND Threat='".$Threat."'";

//$select_result = mysqli_query($query);

if ( mysqli_query($link, $sql, $query)) {    
    echo "New Records added successfully." ;      

} else {
    echo "Please add records." ;
}
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO vuln_threat(Vulnerability, Threat) VALUES ('$Vulnerability', '$Threat') ";
$Vulnerability_count = mysqli("Select count(*) from vuln_threat");

Comment: You aren't executing the insert query

Comment: Oh and dude, even if it is a localhost setup (for now). Never post your db credentials.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query accepts only predefined constants as the 3rd parameter when used in a procedural fashion.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php